# Getting Architecture arm64 issue on my M1 due to which i cant run my old project

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, apple-m1

ld: in /Desktop/Project/ios/Pods/OpenSSL-Universal/ios/lib/libcrypto.a(cryptlib.o), building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file '/ios/Pods/OpenSSL-Universal/ios/lib/libcrypto.a' for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

In /Desktop/Project/ios/Pods/OpenSSL-Universal/ios/lib/libcrypto.a(cryptlib.o), building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file '/Desktop/Project/ios/Pods/OpenSSL-Universal/ios/lib/libcrypto.a' for architecture arm64

I tried arch -x86_64 pod install, all other solutions mentioned here i.e changes in architecture and changing to launch XCODE with rosetta but any of those didn't help. I need to run my old react native project in my M1 Pc with XCODE 14.2 and RN 0.63.3 .

Answer (score 0):

you need to fire this below command

```
react-native bundle --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --platform ios
```